# Object reference set to null C# application

Tags: c#

I have a Code where i am getting data from csv file on name search 
if i type name in textbox1 then deatails related to that person are displayed in the remaining textboxes like surname , city , state

error :[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTRQ.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTRQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdVEZ.png
[image]
Download link of my project :
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTRQ.png)   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTRQ.png): https://www.sendspace.com/file/76vdv5

Code i have written

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace studentdetails
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\vikas\\Desktop\\d.csv";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String con_env = textName.Text.ToString();
            UserDetails ud = SearchFor(con_env);
            textSurname.Text = ud.surname;
            textCity.Text = ud.city;
            textState.Text = ud.state;
        }

        UserDetails SearchFor(String searchName)
        {
            var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in strLines)
            {
                var bits = line.Split(',');
                if (bits[0].Equals(searchName))
                {
                    return new UserDetails()
                    {           
                        surname = bits[1],
                        city = bits[2],
                        state = bits[3],                     
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
}
```

**Userdetails Clas**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace studentdetails
{
    class UserDetails
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Can anyone figure out why this error occurring**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: check SearchFor() method, it return null

Comment: can you correct my code Hien Nguyen

Comment: You should put your file content to question too

Comment: @hien file content isn't necessary, it cannot be null coming from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when your object is not initialized. In your case this error occurred while initializing `UserDetails ud`.

If you debug, you will realize you are returning instance of `UserDetails` from `SearchFor()` function.

When `bits[0].Equals(searchName)` matches at that time it is returning instance of `UserDetails`, but when this condition failed for all records in `foreach` then it is returning null which is not acceptable.

To resolve this issue instead of returning null from `SearchFor()` function, pass instance of `UserDetails` with default parameters.

Something like,

```
 UserDetails SearchFor(String searchName)
        {
            var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in strLines)
            {
                var bits = line.Split(',');
                if (bits[0].Equals(searchName))
                {
                    return new UserDetails()
                    {           
                        surname = bits[1],
                        city = bits[2],
                        state = bits[3],                     
                    };
                }
            }
            return new UserDetails()
                    {           
                        surname = "Default text",
                        city = "Default text",
                        state = "Default text",                     
                    }; //Here you need to fix
        }
```

---

If you do something like above solution, then for failed condition it will set values of `Surname, City and state` to `Default text` which is not correct. To avoid this situation, you can put null check before assigning values to text box

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String con_env = textName.Text.ToString();
        UserDetails ud = SearchFor(con_env);
        //if ud is null then do not set values to text box
        if(ud != null)
        {
           textSurname.Text = ud.surname;
           textCity.Text = ud.city;
           textState.Text = ud.state; 
        }
       else  //else block to set default value
       {
          textSurname.Text = "Default value";
           textCity.Text = "Default value";
           textState.Text = "Default value"; 

        }   
    }


    UserDetails SearchFor(String searchName)
    {
        var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
        foreach (var line in strLines)
        {
            var bits = line.Split(',');
            if (bits[0].Equals(searchName))
            {
                return new UserDetails()
                {           
                    surname = bits[1],
                    city = bits[2],
                    state = bits[3],                     
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: can you correct my code and send me or tell me where do i need to add code so that it works for me

Comment: prasad T working but when i search name in textbox1 as ram the remaing details of that user is not fetched automatically and shown in respected textbox2,textbox3,textbox4

Comment: This is my project Download link of my project : Link 1: https://www.sendspace.com/file/76vdv5    can you correct it for me since two days i am struggling as i am new to c#

Comment: And even all the people in forum special thanks for helping me out ...

Comment: prasad one  more dout how do i set the textbox2,textbox3,textbox4 to default values if i search in textbox 1 then only the default should be replaced with original value form csv file

Comment: Kindly check latest update, I added else block where you can set default values if search in textbox1 is not available.

Comment: Please remove unnecessary comments, it may divert other users.. btw I liked god saver.. comment you can keep it... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code your returning null from the method call below

```
UserDetails ud = SearchFor(con_env);
```

You then try to access a field from that object which is null

```
textSurname.Text = ud.surname;
```

You need to return the UserDetails that you are reading from the file

Comment: can you correct me where to change that to make it work i am new to c#

Answer (score 0):

I did mention in my previous answer (when I gave this code) that the SearchFor method returns a null if the user is not found - when you do your search, and before you try to use the result, you should check if the return value is null. Something like:

```
UserDetails ud = SearchFor(con_env);
if(ud != null){
  surnameTextbox.Text = ud.Surname;
  ...
} else {
  MessageBox.Show("user not found");
}
```

Also note that you seem to have forgotten to set the `name` property of the userdetails object. Check the code i gave in the last answer. Also you should make the properties of the UserDetails class have Names Like This: Surname, City.. "public properties have names starting with a capital letter" is the rule in c# and if you're learning you should get used to doing it now